# MySQL Union?? Query Help

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One has album information, and the other is actual copies of those albums in the inventory.  These have different prices based on various factors.  Each row in the inventory table doesn't store the album information directly, just the id of the album in the "albums" table.

The query I want to write will get me the Artist name, Album Name, image, etc from the albums table as well as the highest and lowest prices found in the inventory table.

I know basic MySQL but I'm having a lot of trouble with this one.  Can some expert please help me here?  Thanks a lot!

Albums table:

- id (pk)
- title
- artist
- year
- genre

Inventory table:

- id(pk)
- albumId (corresponds to an id in albums table)
- price
- condition
- mono

The query I've attempted looks like this but is giving me an error:

```
SELECT albums.artist, albums.title, albums.imgurl, albums.id
  FROM albums

UNION 

SELECT max(inventory.price), min(inventory.price)
 WHERE albums.id = inventory.albumId 
 LIMIT 30

SELECT * FROM `albums`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two parts of a (two-part) UNION must have the same number of columns, and the types need to be the same or treatable as if they were the same.

Your second part doesn't even have a FROM clause.

And the final line is a separate query that should be separated from the previous one by a semi-colon.

What you want is, more or less:

```
 SELECT a.artist, a.title, a.imgurl, a.id, MAX(i.price), MIN(i.price)
   FROM albums    AS a
   JOIN inventory AS i ON a.id = i.albumId
--WHERE ...conditions on artist or album...
  GROUP BY a.artist, a.title, a.imgurl, a.id
```

Note how using table aliases allows the the select-list to fit on one line.  It won't always, of course, but using aliases can provide succinctness, and encourages tagging all columns with the origin table, which helps make it explicit where the data comes from (thereby improving readability and clarity and other fine qualities).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Your response is actually what I orinally had except I used INNER JOIN instead of JOIN and didn't include GROUP BY.  When I ran that query I would only get one response.  I can't test this code at the moment since I am at work, but considering that the guy below you posted the same query I will assume this is correct.  I'll accept it asap when I get home.  Was my problem just because I didn't use a GROUP BY?

Comment: @user379467: You must use GROUP BY when you have a mixture of aggregates and non-aggregates in the select-list.  MySQL allows an abbreviated GROUP BY list (where you only list the primary key column(s) in the GROUP BY clause).  You should be aware, though, that the abbreviated notation is non-standard.  What I wrote should work in any SQL DBMS.

Comment: @user379467: Note that JOIN is an abbreviation for INNER JOIN.  You can also specify {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN and on some systems NATURAL JOIN, and on a few you might be able to use CROSS JOIN (which is basically just a Cartesian product).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT albums.artist, albums.title, albums.imgurl, albums.id,
       max(inventory.price), min(inventory.price)
 FROM albums JOIN inventory ON albums.id = inventory.albumId 
GROUP BY albums.id
```

Comment: Why use a LEFT join?  Avoid them when you are not compelled to use them.  All else apart, they are more expensive than regular inner joins.

Comment: Only MySQL allows the abbreviated GROUP BY list. Since the question is tagged MySQL, it is OK, but it is also non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use UNION like that. The result sets from both queries would have to be the same (i.e. same number of columns and same types) for a [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to work:

> Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the  same data type. (For example, the first column selected by the first statement should have  the same type as the first column selected by the other statements.)

You'll have to do separate queries.